# Cannot declare phptemplate_settings() - Drupal error when trying to configure template

Tags: php, drupal

There are two templates, whitejazz and a modified whitejazz (forumwhitejazz) - both are enabled.

I'm trying to configure the modified whitejazz, and I am getting this error - what does it mean?

Should I post anything else to help deduce this? I'm utterly stumped - my googling of this issue has not given me any solid leads.

This is in Drupal 6.25

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare phptemplate_settings() (previously declared in /home/domain/public_html/drupal-6.25/sites/all/themes/whitejazz/theme-settings.php:3) in /home/domain/public_html/drupal-6.25/sites/all/themes/forumwhitejazz/theme-settings.php on line 135
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that function phptemplate_settings() was defined twice. This goes to fatal php error.

What I suggest to do is:

1. Create file theme-setting.php in root folder of forumwhitejazz template
2. There define function as in example and put there code settings.

Example:

```
function forumwhitejazz_settings($saved_settings) {
  $form = array();

  $form['forumwhitejazz_example'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'checkbox',
    '#title'         => t('Use this sample setting'),
    '#default_value' => $saved_settings['forumwhitejazz_example'],
    '#description'   => t("This option doesn't do anything; it's just an example."),
  );

  return $form;
}
```